# Tableview with dynamicly added rows is empty

Tags: javafx

This code is supposed to show a table with value in it, the columns and rows are added dinamicly ,  the idea of the program is to show a matrix in a tableview ... anyway it shows empty rows, What is the solution ?

```
    private TableView MSTab;


    float MS[][]=new float[n][n];

 for (int s = 1; s < n+1; s++){
                    TableColumn a = new TableColumn(Integer.toString(s));

                    MSTab.getColumns().add(a);
             } 
    ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

                 for (int l=0;l<n;l++){
                     row.removeAll(row);
                 for (int s=0;s<n;s++){

                  row.add(Float.toString(MS[l][s]));

                 }

                    MSTab.getItems().add((ObservableList) row);

                 }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is so much wrong in the code. [Please have a look at the official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm).

**SSCCE:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewSample extends Application {

    private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
    private final ObservableList<Person> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
        );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(500);

        final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

        table.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

        TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
        emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty email;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email.get();
        }

        public void setEmail(String fName) {
            email.set(fName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OH my god!! that code is not the whole code and has no problem while compiling, u didnt get the problem!! looking to ur code , u have fixed the number of column to 3 as "Person" has 3 argument ,.. but I wanted to have a table with n column , and n can take any value not only 3...So thank u , and please if u dont have the answer, just delete this one ...

Comment: 1. Make an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) 2. State what your problem is in more precise terms. Show us what you have tried. 3. Stop ORDERING ME around. -grits his teeth-

Comment: OK, thank u anyway, I apreciate that , and I ll make the SSCCE ;)